# Why did former Yugoslav republics dispute the legal successor of Yugoslavia?

Tags: 20th-century, europe, diplomacy, yugoslavia

In Wikipedia's article for [Yugoslavia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslavia):

> One of the seven successor states was also known as the Federal
>   Republic of Yugoslavia (FRY) until 2003. The FRY aspired to be a sole
>   legal successor to the Socialist Federal Republic of Yugoslavia, but
>   those claims **were opposed by the other former republics**. After the
>   overthrow of Slobodan Milošević from power in 2000, the FRY rescinded
>   those aspirations, accepting the opinion of the Badinter Arbitration
>   Committee about shared succession, and reapplied for and gained UN
>   membership on November 2, 2000

My question: Why did the FRY (Serbia) and the other states dispute which was the legal successor? I roughly know that a legal successor inherits the predecessor state's treaties, positions, rights and obligations, etc. But specifically in this case, what are the benefits of being the successor state of Yugoslavia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The major benefit includes the SFRY's assets and property located abroad in the time of dissolution that was frozen by foreign states in which the assets/property was located.

The assets/property that was of interest to successor states includes foreign currency and gold reserves and embassy buildings.

http://www.csmonitor.com/1996/0918/091896.econ.econ.1.html